# Swift pull down insert form

Tags: ios, swift

I am lost.

I have a TableViewController that is filled programmatically from a collection. I need to show a form when the tableView is pulled down. Right now I have a InsertControl that contains two textFields.
*InsertControl*

```
class InsertControl: UIView {

//MARK: Properties
var name = ""
var quantity = 0

//MARK: Initialization
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let nameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 260, height: 44))
    nameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let quantityTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 270, y: 0, width: 60, height: 44))

    quantityTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    addSubview(nameTextField)
    addSubview(quantityTextField)
}

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 350, height: 44)
}
}
```

then I found that I can put this control in the tableView header, so I have this code in my

*tableViewController*

```
let insertControl = InsertControl()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = insertControl

    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44)
```

The problem is that I need to give to the InsertControl constructor a NSCoder which I don't have.

After I manage to get the form in the header, how can I pass a further swipe down to the control and make it add the content to the tableView collection?

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Could you clarify the last sentence please? After filling in the name and quantity text fields, what is the "swipe" you refer to?

Comment: I'd like to pull down again to insert the text. Like a form submit. But that's secondary. I'd like first to get the control to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, in `InsertControl`, use `override init(frame: CGRect)` instead of `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. It'll look like this:

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let nameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 260, height: 44))
        nameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let quantityTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 270, y: 0, width: 60, height: 44))

        quantityTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        addSubview(nameTextField)
        addSubview(quantityTextField)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 350, height: 44)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, works. But when I insert the control in the table it covers part of the first cell instead of being on top of it.